# SGX psw faced issue

Tags: sgx

I am installing SGX psw when I run make psw I get error

```
 error: ‘SGX_XFRM_PKRU’ was not declared in this scope; did you mean ‘SGX_XFRM_AVX’?
  121 |         se_misc_attr->secs_attr.xfrm &= ~(SGX_XFRM_PKRU);
```

I have to mention that I have run `source /opt/intel/sgxsdk/environment` after installing SGX sdk.